# Searching through RecyclerView using Search Icon - Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am able to search through my recyclerView but then what happens is, the search item when clicked is being affected by the layout postion. For instance i have

- Mac Book Pro
- Nintendo
- Nintendo plus

When i search Nintendo, Nintendo comes only appears in the 1st position. When i click on Nintendo, it gives me the details of Mac Book Pro instead. and when i search for something like `Nint`, it will display Nintendo and Nintendo plus which is cool. But then, since Nintendo plus is apparently in the 2nd position now, when i click on it, it gives me the details of Nintendo. Why is the search not affecting the layout position please?

**Activity**

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {

            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.top_menus, menu);

            var item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.search);

            var searchview = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView)MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(item);

            searchview.QueryTextChange += (s, e) => adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);


            searchview.QueryTextSubmit += (s, e) =>

            {
                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Searched for: " + e.Query, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                e.Handled = true;

            };

            MenuItemCompat.SetOnActionExpandListener(item, new SearchViewExpandListener(adapter));



            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        }

        private class SearchViewExpandListener : Java.Lang.Object, MenuItemCompat.IOnActionExpandListener
        {
            private readonly IFilterable _adapter;

            public SearchViewExpandListener(IFilterable adapter)
            {
                _adapter = adapter;
            }

            public bool OnMenuItemActionCollapse(IMenuItem item)
            {
                _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter("");
                                return true;
            }

            public bool OnMenuItemActionExpand(IMenuItem item)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class GameFilter : Filter
        {
            public readonly GameAdapter _adapter;
            public GameFilter(GameAdapter adapter)
            {
                _adapter = adapter;
            }

            protected override FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)
            {
                var returnObj = new FilterResults();
                var results = new List<Games>();
                if (_adapter._originalData == null)
                    _adapter._originalData = _adapter.games;

                if (constraint == null) return returnObj;

                if (_adapter._originalData != null && _adapter._originalData.Any())
                {

                    results.AddRange(
                        _adapter._originalData.Where(
                            games => games.Name.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString())));
                }

                returnObj.Values = FromArray(results.Select(r => r.ToJavaObject()).ToArray());
                returnObj.Count = results.Count;

                constraint.Dispose();

                return returnObj;


            }

            protected override void PublishResults(ICharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
            {
                    using (var values = results.Values)
                    _adapter.games = values.ToArray<Java.Lang.Object>()
                        .Select(r => r.ToNetObject <Games>()).ToList();

                _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

                constraint.Dispose();
                results.Dispose();           
            }
        }
```

**update**

```
  void OnItemClick(object sender, int position)
            {
 position = rv.GetChildAdapterPosition((Android.Views.View)sender);
 Intent peaceHeroDetail = new Intent(this, typeof(DetailActivity));

 Detail.PutExtra(PeaceHeroDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, test[position].Name);

       StartActivity(Detail);


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your RecyclerView.Adapter code, you need to unsubscribe and subscribe the Click event for when you click on an item. Then, to perform an action, you need to call the RecyclerView (not Adapter) method GetChildAdapterPosition.

Example:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    Item item = this.myItems[position];
    ((ViewHolderItem)holder).Name.Text = item.Name;
    ((ViewHolderItem)holder).Picture.SetImageBitmap(item.Picture);

    // Unsubscribe and subscribe the method, to avoid setting multiple times.
    ((ViewHolderItem)holder).Item.Click -= Item_Click;
    ((ViewHolderItem)holder).Item.Click += Item_Click;
}

private void Item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int position = this.recyclerView.GetChildAdapterPosition((View)sender);
    Item itemClicked = this.myItems[position];
    if(itemClicked.Name == "Nintendo"){
        Toast.MakeText(this.context, "Nintendo", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at my update. I get an error point at this line  position = rv.GetChildAdapterPosition((Android.Views.View)sender); with the cast

Comment: @Zlatan The parameters for the OnItemClick method are (object sender, EventArgs e), instead of (object sender, int position). Also, are you passing the RecyclerView to the Adapter (is rv a variable in the adapter)?

Comment: rv is not a variable in my adapter but in my activity. OnItemClick Method is also not in my adapter but in my activity